# Passwd on desktop gnome

Tags: fedora, gnome, laptop

I get to this often, on a laptop computer, with fedora gnome up to date, I type in wrong passwd too many times, user gets blocked.

edit 2022-02-27

I managed to unlock the user and learn how to do it, I will post a bit on what I did.

But now, I am unable to login gnome.

If I hit ctrl+alt+F2 and get the terminal, it logs in with my user, but on gnome it does not. (I have been through this before as well, and don’t know how to unlock gnome now for this user). Please help.

—-
Question 1 - please, how to unblock this user? (It’s the only user, not able to login with root user, and I don’t know how to get to a terminal only screen)

Question 2

I have booted with rescue disk, mounted the system, chrooted in, and changed that users password.

But now I get “Sorry password authentication did not work” from gnome.

How should I proceed, what else must be done by the rescue cheroot process, please?

Comment: Did you mount the disk with SELinux enabled?  Or did you relabel after rebooting?  Also, do you know what is locking the account?  Do you use pam_tally2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unlock a blocked account you can do `passwd --unlock user_name` where user_name is the user name of the account you are trying to unlock.

Also according to [Fedora documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/FreeIPA_Guide/user-unlock.html) you can do `user-unlock user_name` to unlock a user but at least on my installation the command was not found.